# Calling JavaScript functions from TypeScript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

What's the best way of importing and using JavaScript code within TypeScript?

I'm trying to use stuff like Bootstrap's modal.js within an Angular 2 Component written using TypeScript.

UPDATE:

The solution as suggested was to create a type declaration d.ts file for the js file to forward delcare things I needed to use, then the referenced js file implementation was used at runtime.

Shame there isn't a more automatic direct way but it gets the job done. For many common frameworks these d.ts type declarations are available as mentioned via http://definitelytyped.org/tsd. I also didn't need to comment style reference the d.ts as it was already included in my compiled ts files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use type declaration or write your own. Take a look on this project http://definitelytyped.org/tsd/

It has type definitions for many popular libraries. And also for `angular-ui-bootstrap`.

Then you can reference definition in Typescript like this:

```
///<reference path="../typings/angular-ui-bootstrap/angular-ui-bootstrap.d.ts"/>
```

In general you basically reference a library, then in typescript you should reference a type definition or provide your own declaration, like

```
declare function hex_md5(value: string): string;
```

if you have javascript function `hex_md5` defined somewhere above.

Comment: Alternatively, do not use `///<reference ...`, use a `tsconfig.json` and do not `exclude` the `typings` directory containing the typings definition files; they will be referenced by the compiler automatically.